# Python arrow get list of years between date range

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, arrow-python

I have this function:

```
def function(start_date_arrow=None,end_date_arrow=None, date_concept=None):
    list=[getattr(date, date_concept) for date in arrow.Arrow.range(date_concept, start_date_arrow, end_date_arrow)]
```

This function works well when iterating over `date_concept='month'` and `date_concept='day'`. On the other hand, `date_concept='year'` only returns a list of one item.

For example:

```
start_date_arrow= arrow.get('2021-11-05')
end_date_arrow= arrow.get('2022-02-05')

year_list=function(start_date_arrow=start_date_arrow,end_date_arrow=end_date_arrow, date_concept='year')
year_list is [2021]   

month_list=function(start_date_arrow=start_date_arrow,end_date_arrow=end_date_arrow, date_concept='month')
month_list is [11, 12, 1, 2]

day_list=function(start_date_arrow=start_date_arrow,end_date_arrow=end_date_arrow, date_concept='day')
day_list is [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30]
```

Second and third call are okei, but first one should return [2021,2022] instead of [2021].

Any idea of what is happening in the year call?

Comment: Can you help me understand what `arrow.Arrow.range` is?  I am not familiar with the function.  Is it part of pyarrow?  What datatype is `arrow`?  Is it a module?  A variable?

Comment: @Pace The function returns a list of :class:`Arrow <arrow.arrow.Arrow>` objects, representing an iteration of time between two inputs.

arrow is a module.

Comment: This is related to https://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ not pyarrow (different libraries). I'll edit the tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue.
If you use:

```
start_date_arrow= arrow.get('2021-11-05')
end_date_arrow= arrow.get('2022-02-05')
```

Year difference between both is less than 1, so it only returns the first one, so to return 2022 in the list `end_date_arrow` should be `end_date_arrow= arrow.get('2022-11-05')`

So I forced with an `if` statement the end date to be bigger just by one year, to force the return of both years.